# Angular-material not working in slackblitz

Tags: angular

I am trying to use angular material in slackblitz. But it is not working. Can anyone please help me understand, what I am doing wrong.

[slack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zcmjw8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Thanks

Comment: refer https://stackblitz.com/angular/xaajrxeeqxqk?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.ts
or Any example on https://material.angular.io/components/categories

Comment: What's not working?

Answer (score 1):

Just update your dependencies on your stackblitz and include one of the material design styles sheet, once you do that everything should work.

Here's a fork of your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ixcqgx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)